# Regex match all spaces between two characters

Tags: regex

This should be easy but for some reason I can't get it working.

How do i replace all spaces between '[' and ']' chars?

Here is sample text:

```
[HTTP Referrer] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[Original URL] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[Install App Store] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[Match Type] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[Contributor 1 Match Type] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[Contributor 2 Match Type] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[Contributor 3 Match Type] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[Device Category] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[Google Play Referrer] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[Google Play Click Time] DATETIME2 NULL, 
[Google Play Install Begin Time] DATETIME2 NULL,
[CreatedOn] DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
[ModifiedOn] DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
[Retired] BIT NOT NULL
```

How do I capture the spaces in between brackets:

Desired output after replacing regex matches will be:

```
[HTTPReferrer] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[OriginalURL] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[InstallAppStore] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[MatchType]NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[Contributor1MatchType] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[Contributor2MatchType] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[Contributor3MatchType] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[DeviceCategory] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
[GooglePlayReferrer] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[GooglePlayClickTime] DATETIME2 NULL, 
[GooglePlayInstallBeginTime] DATETIME2 NULL,
[CreatedOn] DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
[ModifiedOn] DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
[Retired] BIT NOT NULL
```

I'm not posting the regex i'm attempting because it is trash so far.  Not even near the mark.

This is getting close:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\[)[^,]*?\K\s(?=[^\]]*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this lookahead regex approach to find all spaces before `]` character:

```
\h+(?=[^]]*\])
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\h+`: Match 1+ horizontal characters
- `(?=[^]]*\])`: Lookahead to assert that we have `]` ahead without any `]` in between

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yMq4uq/1)

Alternatively you may use approach using `\G` as in your question:

```
(?:\[|(?!^)\G)[^]\s]*\K\h+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/yMq4uq/2)

Comment: Your first example doesn't seem to work given the sample data I provided.  Second example was bang on though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a practical example using sed, to locate each space between the brackets by using it as a separator and excluding it from the substitution.

```
t_STR=$(cat /tmp/example.txt); # slurp in the text
for i in $(seq $(echo "$t_STR"|grep -c ' '));do # how many spaces?
   t_STR="$(echo "$t_STR"|sed 's/\(\[.*\) \(.*\]\)/\1\2/g')"; # remove them
done
echo "$t_STR"
```

If there is only a single space within each pair of brackets the:
`sed 's/\(\[.*\) \(.*\]\)/\1\2/' < /tmp/example.txt`
works, (even with /g sed only removed one space with this regexp.)

You are trying to apply a "remove spaces" to the first half of each line, with ']' as the separator, so it might be more efficient, (in some cases) to split the line into two and then `s/ //g` over the first half before joining the two with ']' between them.